# JVM remote monitoring

Tags: monitoring, remote, java

I was trying to configure JVM for remote monitoring but getting the below error on server

```
The configuration has not been set for this resource due to : Invalid configuration: Error contacting resource: Can't connect to MBeanServer [{jmx.username=system, jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:6969/jmxrmi}]: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
```

I want to monitor tomcat server, according to the doc I have add the remote monitoring Mbean Server connection string in /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh file

```
[ $1 != "stop" ] && JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969 \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false $JAVA_OPTS" 
export JAVA_OPTS
```

I have restarted the tomcat service after that. But not able to see port 6969 listening on the server. After restarting the tomcat i have checked it via "netstat -an | grep 696" I think this is the problem. Port 6969 is not used on this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make it work. I added the setting in JAVA_OPTS variable in tomcat startup script as below:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Comment: Dont see the difference between this and the original, all are in catalina.sh how starts the server. ¿right? the only diff is that java.awt.headless... is that was prevented JMX to run? I dont use it and it works for me... ¿Maybe that $1 = Stop was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you are trying to connect to remote jmx. Then how come

> mx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:6969/jmxrmi

localhost on the machine will work ??. I think you should use the IP of the remote machine instead of localhost.

Comment: I am trying on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems correct at 100%. Here's what i use in my Windows enviroment:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9988
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I think in 2 elements that can be the problem:
**The format**. I see u put:

> JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.ma...

Try giving a "space" to that first element, like i do in my configuration.
U can also use a echo after generating the $JAVA_OPST variable, and check that the syntax is correct.

**The other is the JVM Version**. ¿1.5?¿1.6?¿JRE?¿JDK?
Try using the most upgraded (or at least the 1.6) if ur installation is giving u problems.

Answer (score 0):

1) download jmxterm from:
http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm:download
2) copy the downloaded jar file to a test server

3) ssh to the test server

4) on the test server start the JMX shell:

$ java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l localhost:20051

(Note: port 20051 is the port your servers use for JMX.  I looked at the data from one of your servers and saw the following on the javacommand line: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=20051.  If the test server is using a different java command line, you need to locate the same option and the port number if it's different)

5) Test that the shell connected correctly:

$>open

You will something like:

rmi://127.0.1.1  4,service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:3333/jmxrmi

6) List the available Mbeans, copy paste the output and send to me.  We will review what is available and what is needed.

$>beans

7) Check the attributes available from a given bean:

$>bean name_of_object from_output_above (ex.net.lag.kestrel:name=queues.weather_updates,type=Config)

## bean is set to net.lag.kestrel:name=queues.weather_updates,type=Config

$>info

## mbean = net.lag.kestrel:name=queues.weather_updates,type=Config

## class name = net.lag.configgy.ConfigMap

## attributes

%0   - max_age (java.lang.String, rw)

%1   - max_items (java.lang.String, rw)

## operations

%0   - void add_list(java.lang.String key,java.lang.String value)

%1   - void remove(java.lang.String key)